# If Elseif Query

Tags: php, custom-field, query

I'm trying to work this query - the first if clause works, and the else works, but the middle clause, elseif, doesn't work.

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'TourURL', true)) {
            <div class="tourenquiryonline">
            <h2>Book or Inquire</h2>
            This tour can be booked online.
            </div>

} elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bhid', true)){
            echo
                        <div class="tourenquiryonline">
            <h2>Book</h2>
            This tour can be booked online via the form on the right hand side of this page.
                        </div>
} else {
            <div class="tourenquiry">
                        <div id="wufoo-q7x2x3">
                        Fill out my <a href="http://touristisrael.wufoo.com/forms/q7x2x3">online form</a>.
            </div>
}?>
```

Comment: Your PHP is badly broken. You should be getting fatal parse errors.

Comment: The only difference I see in the 3 is an echo in the else if...does it work if you take that out?

Answer (score 1):

This **cannot** work.
It has to look like the following (or similar):

```
<?php
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'TourURL', true)) {
    ?>
    <div class="tourenquiryonline">
        <h2>Book or Inquire</h2>
        This tour can be booked online.
    </div>
    <?php
} elseif (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bhid', true)) {
    ?>
    <div class="tourenquiryonline">
        <h2>Book</h2>
        This tour can be booked online via the form on the right hand side of this page.
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <div class="tourenquiry">
        <div id="wufoo-q7x2x3">
        Fill out my <a href="http://touristisrael.wufoo.com/forms/q7x2x3">online form</a>.
        </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**// Edit**
And as you can see, you are missing a closing `</div>` in the `else` case.

Comment: Thanks. But this still doesn't work...

I don't get errors, but the elesif still doesn't produce results

Comment: Well, then that's because either the `'bhid'` post meta is `false`, or it is `true` but the `'TourURL'` post meta is `true` as well - which won't let you enter the `elseif`.

Comment: bhid is true and working because it is populating a field in the sidebar, but this is to show or hide a piece of content in the main body... TourURL' is definitely false...

Comment: Well, then please do me a favor, and dump the data in question, compare the data with the current setup (i.e., the `if ... elseif ... else ...` block), and then figure out what you have to do to make it work like you want it to. How do you do this? Like so: `echo 'TourURL: '; var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'TourURL', true)); echo "\n".'bhid: '; var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bhid', true));`. Put this right before the `if`. I'm pretty sure this will explain to you, why _this still doesn't work_.

Answer (score -1):

what´s about switch case with php?

```
switch ($i) {
case 0:
    echo "i equals 0";
    break;
case 1:
    echo "i equals 1";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "i equals 2";
    break;
```

}

Comment: i equals 2 can be replaced with if a value is present..?